# INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, owner or user is inactive

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader, after-trigger

I got an issue when I want to load (data through Talend) to Salesforce.

When I do the upsert, I have like 50% of upsert errors with this message :

> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:UserTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 38  first error: **INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, owner or user is inactive.** Org Id:00XXXXXXXXXXXXXX: [].

Here is the line in error in my code :
**Class.User_UTL.assignPermissionSetAndGroup: line 18, column 1**

```
 public static void assignPermissionSetAndGroup(Map<Id, User> newUserMap){
    List<User> newUsers = newUserMap.values();
    List<PermissionSetAssignment> psaList = User_SVE.constructPermissionSetAssignment(newUsers);
    List<GroupMember> groupList = User_SVE.constructGroupAssignment(newUsers);
    if(psaList.size()>0){
        insert(psaList); // **LINE 18**
    }
    if(groupList.size()>0){
        insert(groupList);
    }
}
```

So the "psaList" is made here :

```
    public static List<PermissionSetAssignment> constructPermissionSetAssignment(List<User> newUsers){
    List<PermissionSetAssignment> psaList = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
    Set<String> fonctions = new Set<String>();
    for(User u : newUsers){
        if(String.isNotBlank(u.Fonction__c)){
            fonctions.add(u.Fonction__c);
        }
    }

    if(fonctions.size()>0){
        List<CMT008_PermissionSet__mdt> cmPS = [SELECT Fonction__c, PermissionSet__c
                                                FROM CMT008_PermissionSet__mdt
                                                WHERE Fonction__c IN :fonctions
                                                ORDER BY Fonction__c];
        Set<String> psNameSet = new Set<String>();
        for(CMT008_PermissionSet__mdt cm : cmPS){
            if(String.isNotBlank(cm.PermissionSet__c)){
                psNameSet.add(cm.PermissionSet__c);
            }
        }
        if(psNameSet.size()>0){
            List<PermissionSet> permissionSets = [SELECT Id, Name
                                                  FROM PermissionSet
                                                  WHERE Name IN : psNameSet];
            Map<String, Id> psMap = new Map<String, Id>();
            for(PermissionSet ps : permissionSets){
                psMap.put(ps.Name, ps.Id);
            }

            Map<String,Set<String>> fpsMap = new Map<String, Set<String>>();

            for(CMT008_PermissionSet__mdt cm : cmPS){
                if(!fpsMap.containsKey(cm.Fonction__c)){
                    fpsMap.put(cm.Fonction__c, new Set<String>());
                }
                fpsMap.get(cm.Fonction__c).add(psMap.get(cm.PermissionSet__c));
            }
            for(User u : newUsers){
                if(fpsMap.containsKey(u.Fonction__c)){
                    for(Id psId : fpsMap.get(u.Fonction__c)){
                        psaList.add(new PermissionSetAssignment(
                            AssigneeId = u.Id,
                            PermissionSetId = psId
                        ));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return psaList;
}
```

The code is just looking after a value contained in the field "Fonction__c", and search for the good permission set to be assigned to the user I want to insert/update (upsert)

I really don't understand what's going on...
**The user I use to do the job is "ACTIVE", and all my users in my .csv are set to "isActive" = true.**

Is someone have an idea to fix that problem ?

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: I'd review the list of users you're furnishing in there. That error will appear if any of the users being assigned a PermSet is inactive.

Comment: Hi @SebastianKessel thanks for your answer. Is there a way to be able to assign a permset to an inactive user no ? With the Audit perm ?

Comment: As far as I know, no. You have to activate, assign, then deactivate again